# How can I display an user photo on the page with PHP?

Tags: php, wordpress

I have a web site and want to allow users to submit a profile photo. I am fine having them email me the photo which I add manually (need to do this since I have custom PHP pages and turned the WordPress bar off).

My question is this:

I can dynamically get the user info in wordpress using:

```
$user_info = get_userdata( $theID );
```

But how can I display the photo for that user when someone clicks on that user to view their profile. Since I am using PHP, what might the path and code be to call the photo for that user and display it on the page?

Comment: It depends. How do you recognize the user, when you provide his information in their profiles?

Answer (score 2):

Have you tried using [`get_avatar()`](http://codex.wordpress.org/Function_Reference/get_avatar)? Consider this example:

```
$user_info = get_userdata($theID); // return an object with the corresponding info
if ( ($user_info instanceof WP_User) ) {
    echo get_avatar( $user_info->user_email, 32 ); // second paramter size
    // return an <img> tag with the users avatar
}
```

Comment: exactly, you beat me to it

Comment: @Fabio lol, if you posted ahead i would have upvoted as well, seems to me this is the logical answer

Comment: no, I was posting the answer, saw an answer was already posted, and it was more or less the same, so mine was unneeded, simply voted yours because it's correct (well, at least for what I understand of the question)

Comment: Interesting. But let's say you email me a photo and user name. I go into user user settings and add the photo and this will override the avatar I assume? I'm thinking if (there is a photo display) else (click here to submit a photo for review)

Comment: @jaw thats a good idea, but the trick here is that, `get_avatar` returns an img string already, i doesn't say when the user doesn't have a photo yet, `get_avatar()` doesn't really return a `false`, actually i'm checking the codex, seems no option for that

Comment: That's unfortunate. There must be a fairly common way to get a user photo and display on a page, but i can't find any photo info for user_info. Wish it was as simple as $user_info->user_photo or something...

Comment: @jaw yes i thought so too, there isn't really a direct way to do it, can't find anything in the wp codex